# Using MATLAB svmtrain

Tags: matlab, svm

This is my first Matlab program.

I'm trying to use svmtrain and svmclassify with custom kernel.

Assume my kernel is regular inner product.

How should I write it?

I did:

```
function [K] = mykernel(U, V)
    for i=size(U,1)
        for j=size(V,1)
            K(i,j) = dot(U(i,:),V(j,:));
        end
    end
    return 
end
```

and then in the command window:

```
x=randn(1000,10);
w=rand(1,10);
y=sign(x*w');
a=svmtrain(x,y,'kernel_function',mykernel);
```

and I get:

```
Error using mykernel (line 2)
Not enough input arguments.
```

Maybe one has a trick to do it without loops, something like U*V', it'll be nice to know this 
trick, but i need to do it in loop, since i'm going to change the inner product to some more complicated stuff.

I also didn't really understand what are those U,V, and I didn't really get what this function 
should return (is it the Gram matrix?)

Thanks for your help!!

--- EDIT:

I did the following:

```
function [K] = mink(U, V)
    for i=1:size(U,1)
        for j=1:size(V,1)
            K(i,j) = min(exp(-dot(U(i,:),U(j,:))),exp(-dot(V(i,:),V(j,:))));
        end
    end
    return 
end

>>x=randn(100,10);
>>w=rand(1,10);
>>y=sign(x*w');
>>a=svmtrain(x,y,'kernel_function',@mink);
>>svmclassify(a, x)
Error using svmclassify (line 114)
An error was encountered during classification.
Attempted to access U(89,:); index out of bounds because size(U)=[88,10].
```

so now svmtrain works but svmclassify complains about size mismath (how did it get 88??)

Comment: btw when i do svmtrain(x,y,'kernel_function','linear'); or any other predefined kernel, everything works great

Comment: Check your for loop. It seems like you want `i=1:size(....)`

Comment: right. it was just a typo here. pls see my last edit

Comment: What's the size of your y? It's not a vector of groups is it?

Comment: do you know what are those u,v? they have the same dimension of x!

Answer (score 1):

In order to pass a function, you need to use the `@` symbol. This is shown in [the docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/svmtrain.html), which quote:

> @kfun — Function handle to a kernel function. A kernel function must be of the form

Bottom line, this will work.

```
a=svmtrain(x,y,'kernel_function',@mykernel);
```

Comment: you're right, i tried that either and saw the function being called, but i still cant get it work. can you please explain me what i should do with U,V? the strange thing is that they have the same dimensions as x.

Comment: Most likely you simply want `K=U.*V;`. But I'm not sure what function you really want, so...

Comment: yes but what are u,v? are they just x? so why two params? when i do disp(u),disp(v), i see they're different from one call to another. what's going on here?

say i'd like the i,j element of my gram matrix to be min(exp(-||A||),exp(-||B||)), where A is x's i'th row and B is x's j'th row. hwo should I write my function then? (ignore the fact that it doesn't look like a good kernel, just for me to learn how to speak with that matlab). thanks!!!

Comment: They would be x and y. Wikipedia touches on this at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine#Formal_definition

Comment: but when i display their size, they have the size of x rather than y. pls see my edit